# Custom module not working in magento 2.1.x

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have created one module through which we can create upload images & from product detail page we can get the list of those images in a grid & whatever images we select those will be seen in front in product page.

This module works fine in Magento 2.0.x but not working in magento 2.1.x the problem is here :-

We have one observer which is being called when we save the product & in that we get the product id & the selected images ids....now the issue is we do not get images ids in 2.1.x

Event is : catalog_product_save_after

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="sticker" instance="Els\Sk\Observer\Adminhtml\Product" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here is our Observer Code :-

```
<?php 
namespace Els\Sk\Observer\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Product implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $resourceConnection;
    protected $eavAttributeFactory;
    protected $request;
    protected $_resources;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
       $this->eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory;
    }


    /**
     * Saving product images data.
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $product_id = $product->getId();

        /* We are not getting this in 2.1.x so this is the real issue */
        $images_ids = $this->request->getPost("images_id");

        $this->imageInsert($images_ids , $product_id);
    }
?>
```

Can any one please help with this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please add full class so we can see dependency

Comment: Are you sure this Observer was call after you save the product ?

Comment: Thank you Murtuza for looking into this :) Please see the updated question, we have added full definition of observer & also included observer event.

Comment: Thank you Toan for looking into this :) Please see the updated question, we have added full definition of observer & also included observer event & yes it is being called after product save.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) { 
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}
```

inside your `execute` function use below code to get post data.

```
$this->_request->getPost();
```

clear **cache**.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, we tried this but no luck :(
Any other solution please?